# Autofixture Fixture.Build().With() On Same Property Name

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

When i set property with "with" method, its leave null all propertys on nested objects which same named.

(im using autofixture's latest version as 3.0.8)

```
public class Something {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Something> Things { get; set; }
}

var obj = Fixture.Build<Something>().With(q => q.Id, "something").CreateAnonymous()
```

In this situation, obj.Id == "something" equals to true, but also obj.Things[0].Id == null equalsto true.

I think there is a bug or im mistaken; Anyone may help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, AutoFixture will not create an instance of `Something` because the graph contains a circular reference.

What you can do is to add / remove the appropriate behaviors on the `Fixture` instance:

```
fixture.Behaviors.Remove(new ThrowingRecursionBehavior());
fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());
```

You can now create an instance of `Something` however the `Things` property (circular reference) is now omitted.

That's *why* you get an empty list..

However, you can customize the creation algorithm even further:

```
var obj = fixture.Build<Something>()
    .With(x => x.Id, 
        "something")
    .With(x => x.Things, 
        fixture.CreateMany<Something>().ToList())
    .Create();
```